# Pattern for knowing when a method can be called in a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a `Device` interface:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    double Measure();
}
```

Some classes that implement that interface have a measuring instrument:

```
public class InstrumentedDevice : IDevice
{
    public MeasuringInstrument Instrument { get; set; }

    public double Measure()
    {
        if (Instrument != null)
            return Instrument.DoMeasuring();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'd like to group the instances of `InstrumentedDevice` according to their `Instrument` property so that the result is a collection of groups in which each device uses the same instrument as all the other devices in its group.

I'd then like to start a new thread for each group and perform the measuring in parallel.

That would look something like this:

```
public void MeasureAllDevices(IEnumerable<InstrumentedDevice> devices)
{
    var groups = devices.GroupBy(d => d.Instrument);
    foreach (var gr in groups)
    {
        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var device in gr)
            {
                device.Measure();
            }
        };
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();        
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't get a collection of `InstrumentedDevice` as the parameter for `MeasureAllDevices`. I get a collection of `IDevice`:

```
public void MeasureAllDevices(IEnumerable<IDevice> devices)
{

}
```

**My question is this**: Is there a pattern I can follow to solve my problem? Not all devices will have a `MeasuringInstrument`, and some devices may have different means of determining whether or not they can be measured in parallel.

I'd like to add something to the `IDevice` interface like `CanBeMultiThreadedWith(IDevice other)`, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Is it possible for you to group the devices before you pass them into the MeasurAllDevices method, while they are still typed as their derived types?

Comment: Maybe... are you suggesting I do: MeasureAllDevices(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IDevice>> deviceGroups) -- and then process each group in a new thread?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm proposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string GroupBy {get;}
    double Measure();
}
```

Comment: This might work. The GroupBy string would have to be sort of funky in order to maintain its uniqueness among types but also allow it to be the same for instances of the type that need it to be. I'll give it a try.

Comment: funky how? there would be a different implementation for each implementation of `IDevice`. it doesn't matter how the string is created, only that it's unique per group. from the consuming side it's just a string.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my first answer misunderstood the problem. Here is a new one:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    double Measure();
    string ConcurrencyGroupName { get; }
}
```

Every device gets a new "concurrency group name". The convention is that only device who have this name equal can be processed in parallel.

So you .GroupBy the ConcurrencyGroupName and foreach group you process its items in parallel.

This way the devices decide if they want to execute in parallel or not. Your central piece of code that does the processing will never have to be modified.

Your InstrumentedDevice class would just return the name of the instrument or its ID as the 
ConcurrencyGroupName. Other implementations would be possible, too.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll do. Jason's answer came first, though, so I'll have to give him the check.

Comment: His was not as well explained... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the devices in ones that are instrumented and ones that aren't:

```
var measurable = devices.OfType<InstrumentedDevice>().ToList();
var notMeasurable = devices.Except(measurable).ToList();
```

You can process the two sets independently.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know all of the possible types at compile time. Each type can have a different method of determining whether or not it can be multi-threaded with other instances of that type. That's why I'd like to add something to the IDevice interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MeasuringInstrument Instrument(this IDevice device)
{
  if (device is InstrumentedDevice)
  {
    return (device as InstrumentedDevice).Instrument;
  }

  return null;
}


var groups = devices.GroupBy(d => d.Instrument());
foreach (var gr in groups)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know all of the possible types at compile time. Each type can have a different method of determining whether or not it can be multi-threaded with other instances of that type. That's why I'd like to add something to the IDevice interface.